# Centering a Form simply using Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to bootstrap and my code:

```
<form method="POST" name="checker" action="process-form-data.php" onsubmit="return blankCheck()">
  <p><input type="text" class="form-control" name="said"></p>
  <p><input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
```

Im trying to shorten the width of an input text field with bootstrap.  When I use the  tag with bootstrap's grid system, I cannot center the input anymore.  Right now the input spans the whole page and I'd like to only be about 20 characters long.  Thanks.
Here is how it shows up: [web page](http://code.the.com/)

Comment: The page you linked to has the button and input centered.

Answer (score 0):

Using bootstrap grid system is almost easy: just think in a grid with 12 blocks, so adding `col-md-8` and `col-md-offset-2` the form will be centered with a width off "8 blocks".

[image]

I've also added `col-md-12` to the next paragraph in order to keep it down. Maybe there's a cleaner way (defining containers for example), but this quick fix works.

Comment: Do you know how to use containers because I'm working on another page where there are multiple items I want to keep below a bootstrap item.

Comment: Em yes, but there's no so much theory. Just use `container` class in an element and it will try to fill all the space available. The easiest way is to use a big element (bootstrap shows a div but I prefer using sections and/or articles because of the meaning) and place all your content inside it. Here you have the [link to bootstrap's containers](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container).